# Есть ли разница между DDOS атаками на облачный и на обычный сервер?

Tags: ddos, облако

Интересно есть ли какая то разница в DDOS атаке или защите облачного сервера от обычного сервера? Никакой точной информации нигде не смог найти

Comment: по большому счёту нет разницы. но ответственность за облачный сервер в большей степени лежит на провайдере.

Answer (score 1):

Все конечно зависит от настроек обычного сервера, но облачные сервисы (топовые) как правило имеют очень надежную защиту от DDOS если следовать гайдлайнам по настройкам, а есть и сторонние сервисы, которые специализируется на защите от DDOS и их легко интегрировать с не топовыми, например [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/).

За точной информацией, следует обращаться к каждому конкретному провайдеру облачных сервисов. Например AWS предлагает решать проблему [так](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DDoS_White_Paper_June2015.pdf).

Comment: Как правило все-таки не имеют. Cloudflare просто именно этим зарабатывает на жизнь.

Answer (score 0):

Как совершенно верно заметил Сеня, всё зависит от настроек обычного сервера. Надо понимать, что облако это лишь платформа и как там всё организованно и есть ли встроенная защита от DDoS атак, зависит от самой платформы.

К примеру в Microsoft Azure существует хорошая встроенная защита от DDoS. Это описанно [в данном документе](https://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj27_Swx5bNAhXGORQKHe7YARIQFggpMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fc%2Fa%2F3%2Fca3fc5c0-ece0-4f87-bf4b-d74064a00846%2Fazurenetworksecurity_v2_oct2014.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEK5qqNtY65HvIEQpF2-SD3Vpd7wQ). Но надо заметить, что разные облачные сервисы защищены по разному. Имею ввиду при этом, что помимо виртуальных машин в облаке существуют и другие методы хостинга приложений, да и вообще совершенно новые сервисы практически не имеющие аналогов в On Premise мире. Соответсвенно, если вам нужна информации по защите конкретного серивса, то и гуглить надо конкретно по сервису.

Answer (score -3):

Что касается Сloudflare, я бы его не рекомендовал, он для Буржуев и не годится для наших СНГ-сограждан. Роскомнадзор так же убедительно просит не пользоваться сервисом CloudFlare.

Comment: Stack Overflow использует Cloud Flare. Думаете, Stack Overflow не годится для ваших сограждан?

Comment: Я отталкиваюсь от того с чем лично приходилось сталкиваться. Ответ основан на фактах, и не подразумевает вопросов на мой ответ. В конце концов я выразил своё, личное мнение по теме. Что-то и кому то доказывать - не собираюсь. Вы можете не соглашаться с моим ответом и оставаться при своём мнении.